# google page scan and backlinks

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks

As i seen using google webmaster tools, google was cahing near about all links present on a webpage of my site.

I just want to be ensure, if there is an external link present on my webpage outside the main contents (like sidebar, comments, post footer) then would it be counted as backlink to that side.

For example, if i let a plugin to display "credit to" or "powered by" etc link then would it be counted as backlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link is a link. Those links are just as viable as any other external link. Their location on the page doesn't matter. Unless you nofollow it it will carry whatever weight links from that page carry.

Comment: I have a plugin which is having a credit link pointing to my site. As per my calculation there should be around 200-500 sites using my plugin. would it increase backlinks to my site.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you are getting at, but if you link to another site then it's just a link. There have been rumours that external links in footers etc are given less weight but I don't think there is any real evidence, and any reduction would be small. It would still pass PageRank.

This is not something worth worrying about.